# How to move files automatically in PHP

Tags: php, race-condition

I have following scenario. Typically a work distribution application. Here is the story.

There are 10 concurrent users actively online.

In one folder, for example `/home/Queue/`

there are 5 text files:

```
/home/Queue/dg37.txt
/home/Queue/aa.txt
/home/Queue/dsvdsl.txt
/home/Queue/gf4.txt
/home/Queue/ddef.txt
```

These 10 concurrent users each needed to move one file into their respective folder. This file contains job instruction.

Imagine that these 10 users are concurrently moving one text file to their respective home folder.

How do I code the PHP code so that it's an automatic operation, that is only 5 users will able to get the text file in their respective home folder and 5 other users will get **currently no job for you** message.

Thankyou.

Comment: A database that uses column to represent if the file is checked in our out.

Comment: What if we cannot use database?

Comment: Just moving the file directly to users directory (So not copy but a `Cut and Paste` in Windows terminology. You can use `rename()` for this.

Comment: I imagine my implementation is like this. Each concurrent user list all the text files in queue directory. Using the loop, each user concurrently move one file to their respective home folder, concurrently. Out of 10 users, only one user able to move the text file. What happen to the other 9 users when the file they were trying to move already not there? Assuming PHP will return the file list in same order and each user loop and move happened concurrently.

Comment: See my answer, `rename()` returns a boolean to let you know if it's failed or not. If it's failed, then someone has already taken that text file if true then you know they have that file to work on. You could even go as far as using AJAX to communicate with your PHP function every second to so the users page is always showing the latest files in the directory without refreshing.

Comment: I understood your solution. Thankyou. Now working on real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, I would advise using a database and flags, but another method would be to remove the file from the queue direct into another folder. Using the `rename()` function, you are able to move the file straight to away to another directory (similar to a cut and paste in Windows). It also returns a boolean which you could use to your advantage in case two people do click on the item at roughly the same time.

```
rename ("/home/Queue/dg37.txt", "/home/users/bob/queue/dg37.txt");
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: I got your solution. Thankyou. Now working on the real code. Will report back the result.